# Java: Bubble sort somehow not working

Tags: java, arraylist, bubble-sort

Ok, this is really embarrassing, but I have a bubble sort that doesn't seem to fully sort the data each time. I have gone over it even on paper, but I can't find any problems with it. (The below is supposed to sort the largets to the left, and the smallest to the right.

```
 //Sort multiplicity by number of each card, bubble sort
        int out, in;
        for (out = multi.size() - 1; out > 1; out--) {
            for (in = 0; in < out; in++) {
                if (multi.get(in).getValue() < multi.get(in + 1).getValue()) {
                    CardMultiplicity temp = multi.get(in);
                    multi.set(in, multi.get(in+1));
                    multi.set(in+1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
```

Note: multi is an Arraylist of a particular type, which shouldn't be important here.
Generally, I get it almost sorted, but it seems like it is one pass short sometimes. Is something missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your loop:

`for (out = multi.size() - 1; out > 1; out--) {`

You should change:

`out > 1`

To:

`out > 0`

Comment: Hehehehehe, I knew it was something stupidly simple, but I guess I was too immersed in the code to see it. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is more stupid than not asking after trying :) Things like this happens.. compiler might help in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

the first loop runs till out<1 hence the it does not reaches the 0th row, since the inner loop also runs till the out value. correction required.

```
for (out = multi.size() - 1; out > 0; out--)//should do the trick
```